# Remove sequentially duplicate frames in p5.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-processing, p5.js

1. In the code below I want to get the first 120 frames.
2. Then I want to remove the sequentially duplicate ones

`ffmpeg` has a [mpdecimate](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#mpdecimate) filter that is supposed to drop frames that don't vary greatly from each other.

But I don't know if there is an ffmpeg Js library (or equivalent) to do something like that within a p5.js context.

```
function setup() {
  frameRate(24)
  video = createCapture(VIDEO)
  video.size(videoWidth, videoHeight)
  video.hide()

  createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasWidth)
}

let frames       = []
let uniqueFrames = []
let STOP         = false

function draw() {

  if (video && video.loadedmetadata && frameCount <= 100) {
    frames.push(image(video.get()))
  } else if (!STOP) {
    STOP = true
    uniqueFrames = removeDuplicates(frames)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is take absolute difference between two frames.

When you do that the result will be an image that is completely black if all the pixels match otherwise you'll have brighter pixels where the frames differ. It's a basic technique for a very useful one for a bunch of traditional computer vision tasks.

What you could do is write a function that takes in two frames, computes the absolute difference, counts the non zero pixels and returns that. This value would be useful in an if condition against a threshold value: maybe the frames don't need to be 100% identical, but if they're let's say 85% percent identical then you can mark that as a duplicate.

[Kyle McDonald's Frame Difference p5.js example](https://editor.p5js.org/kylemcdonald/sketches/SyPxxD9hX) is great !

For reference I'm simply listing Kyle's example here:

```js
// https://kylemcdonald.github.io/cv-examples/

var capture;
var previousPixels;
var w = 640;
var h = 480;

function setup() {
    capture = createCapture({
        audio: false,
        video: {
            width: w,
            height: h
        }
    }, function() {
        console.log('capture ready.')
    });
    capture.elt.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
    capture.size(w, h);
    createCanvas(w, h);
    capture.hide();
}

function copyImage(src, dst) {
    var n = src.length;
    if (!dst || dst.length != n) dst = new src.constructor(n);
    while (n--) dst[n] = src[n];
    return dst;
}

function draw() {
    capture.loadPixels();
    var total = 0;
    if (capture.pixels.length > 0) { // don't forget this!
        if (!previousPixels) {
            previousPixels = copyImage(capture.pixels, previousPixels);
        } else {
            var w = capture.width,
                h = capture.height;
            var i = 0;
            var pixels = capture.pixels;
            var thresholdAmount = select('#thresholdAmount').value() * 255. / 100.;
            thresholdAmount *= 3; // 3 for r, g, b
            for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                    // calculate the differences
                    var rdiff = Math.abs(pixels[i + 0] - previousPixels[i + 0]);
                    var gdiff = Math.abs(pixels[i + 1] - previousPixels[i + 1]);
                    var bdiff = Math.abs(pixels[i + 2] - previousPixels[i + 2]);
                    // copy the current pixels to previousPixels
                    previousPixels[i + 0] = pixels[i + 0];
                    previousPixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 1];
                    previousPixels[i + 2] = pixels[i + 2];
                    var diffs = rdiff + gdiff + bdiff;
                    var output = 0;
                    if (diffs > thresholdAmount) {
                        output = 255;
                        total += diffs;
                    }
                    pixels[i++] = output;
                    pixels[i++] = output;
                    pixels[i++] = output;
                    // also try this:
                    // pixels[i++] = rdiff;
                    // pixels[i++] = gdiff;
                    // pixels[i++] = bdiff;
                    i++; // skip alpha
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // need this because sometimes the frames are repeated
    if (total > 0) {
        select('#motion').elt.innerText = total;
        capture.updatePixels();
        image(capture, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DifferenceImage</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        Threshold: <input type="range" id="thresholdAmount" value="25">
    </p>
    <p>
        Motion: <span id="motion">0</span>
    </p>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

See it in action [here](https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelik/sketches/ILVxjbfKc).

Good luck encapsulating the frame difference code into a reusable function which you can call in `removeDiplicates()`.

Comment: Turns out there is an `ffmpeg.js` library so I will try `ffmpeg`'s `mpdecimate` filter. Thanks!

Comment: Wow I tried your example and it's pretty amazing :) I've included the link in your answer. Not sure how to integrate this in my problem though :D.

Comment: So if `total > 0` then the current frame is the same as the previous one and I can ignore the current frame, is that it ?

Comment: Would you say that this refactoring is valid: https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelik/sketches/ILVxjbfKc ?

Comment: I did not know about ffmpeg's mpdecimate: that's cool! Thanks for sharing.
Well done on the refactoring. `total` is counting the number of pixels that are different (given the threshold). If `total == 0` then all the pixels between current previous frame match (notice the result is completely black frame). Does that make sense ?

Comment: yes it does, thanks!

Comment: Can you tell why my unique frames are not being drawn at the end: https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelik/sketches/ILVxjbfKc ? :-/

Comment: So close! There are two gotchas there: 1. you're pushing a base64 encoded representation of the frames: if you want to render with `image()` just store a copy of the p5.Image (e.g. `uniqueFrames.push(capture.get())`), 2. the `else` where you attempted to render the frames using `image()` only gets called once: you probably meant to add an `else` at a higher level, right before the end of `draw()`, 3. optional: you might enjoy using `%`: `index = (index + 1) % uniqueFrames.length;`